# SwiftUI toggle State bool onTapGesture using main tread

Tags: swiftui

I wrote the following to attempt to display a "arrow.down.circle.fill" and then when tapped display a progress view until tasks are done on the main tread. I then want to display the down arrow image again. I noticed it works fine when using a background thread, but then my UI in my main view doesn't update because published changes on background threads aren't allowed.

```
struct TestAnimation: View {
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        if !isLoading {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .onTapGesture {
                    DoSomthingMainTread()
                }
        }
        else {
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
                .padding(30)
                .scaleEffect(3)
        }
    }
    
    func DoSomthingMainTread(){
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            isLoading = true
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                sleep(3) //call function here
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things on the wrong queues.

```
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            isLoading = true // NO!!!! This needs to be on the main queue.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                sleep(3) // NO!!! This should be off the main queue.
            }
            isLoading = false // NO!!! This needs to be on the main queue.
        }
```

You must update `isLoading` on the main queue, because it is a property of a `View`. And you should not perform slow, blocking work (like `sleep(3)`) on the main queue, because it prevents the user interface from responding to user actions.

Your `DoSomthingMainTread` method should look like this:

```
    func DoSomthingMainTread(){
        // Already on main queue because onTapGesture's body runs on main queue.
        isLoading = true

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // On background queue, so OK to perform slow, blocking work.
            sleep(3) //call function here

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Back on main queue, so OK to update isLoading.
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this problem is often encountered in my daily development and I prefer to use `.redacted` first, but here I will provide a method base on your method.

First of all, in the view body it's better to use `ZStack`, so the view will be changed into following code:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
                .padding(30)
                .scaleEffect(3)
                .opacity(isLoading ? 1: 0)

            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .onTapGesture {
                    DoSomthingMainTread()
                }
                .opacity(isLoading ? 0: 1)
        }
    }
```

Notice here I use `.opacity` to decide whether to show the `Image` or not. And in the `DoSomthingMainTread()` method, change the code to:

```swift
    func DoSomthingMainTread(){
        isLoading = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
```

That's my answer, hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others **never `sleep` on the main thread**

**unless**… you use Swift Concurrency, a `Task` sleeps without blocking the thread

```
Task { @MainActor in
    isLoading = true
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000)
    isLoading = false
}
```

Or if you want to do something in the background and update the loading state on the main thread create an extra function dispatched to the `@MainActor`

```
@MainActor func updateLoadingState(_ flag : Bool) {
    isLoading = flag
}
```

and use a detached Task for the background work

```
Task.detached(priority: .background) {
    await updateLoadingState(true)
    doSomethingInBackground()
    await updateLoadingState(false)
}
```